# Combined SVG does not move by pixel while translating

Tags: ruby, svg, html5-canvas

I am using Ruby to combine a list of existed SVG (trigger with XHR by `react-inlinesvg` - if someone wants to know) to display it on my views. The existed SVG size are all 90x90 . By using `rmagick` I can get its bounding box size, then translate the next element with these size. A simplified code will be like this:

```
# Preparing svg, <svg> tag, xml, etc..
...
divider = ''
shift = 0
svg_path.map do |svg|     
  canvas = ImageList.new(svg) # from rmagick
  canvas.trim!
  width =  canvas.columns # get the bounding box after trimming
  content = svg_content(svg) # Read content of existed svg
  output = "<g transform='translate(#{shift}, 0)'>" + content +"</g>" + divider
  shift += width + 10 # A small space between each svg
  # Add divider
  divider = "<g transform='translate(#{shift}, 0)'>" + @divider + "</g>"
end
...
# Add </svg> tag
```

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQTVo.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20agd.jpg)

The link above is a demonstration for my problem, the real SVG is much more complicated.

The problem here is: I can get the exactly size of each element by pixel, however when I translating the next element with those sizes, it does not move as I expected.

Comment: It seems you have `expected` and `result` mismatching their corresponding image. I'd think `expected` would have the gap.

Comment: @Duopixel: thank you. I've updated my question.

Comment: How about linking the input and output SVGs? It's hard to debug a thumbnail.  Also, what are the widths being returned by rmagick? It seems there is a lot of debugging you could still do yourself.